# When using case when in QGIS 3, even without else, all other previously filled cells are replaced by NULL

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table

I would like to update a column with different strings based on other strings in another column.
For instance : if A, B, C in column 1, write Cat1 in column 2. So I use "case when". But even without writing 'else' when it always replace all other values by NULL. Which means that if I then want to update again the column with "if X, Y, Z in column 1, write Cat2 in column 2", "Cat1" gets deleted in all the cells where it had been added. If I don't want to update all cells at the same time, how can I conditionally update certain cells while ignoring others (i.e. not deleting their content)?

Comment: Try using if-statement with a nested `CASE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if("Column 1" IN ('X','Y','Z'),'Cat2',"Column 2")`

This checks whether the specified condition `Column 1 is like X, Y, or Z` is fulfilled and then either writes `Cat2` into Column 2, or uses preexisting values or Column 2 otherwise.

You could also chain several `if` statements, or run a comprehensive `case when when when when` expression.

---

Similar to your question from earlier:

```
CASE
   WHEN "l_co" in ('Romainville','Bagnolet' ,'Bobigny','Bondy' ,'Les Lilas','Montreuil','Noisy-le-Sec' ,'Le Pré-Saint-Gervais','Pantin')
   THEN 'Est Ensemble'
   WHEN "l_co" in (several other city names)
   THEN 'Plaine Commune group'
   ELSE "EPCI"
END
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect. What I was missing was writing ELSE "Column" (Column being the name of the column I am updating) which keeps in place other values.

Answer (score 5):

Why not not just sort and select, or filter, on the values you want to update and use "update selected" or "update filtered"?
[image]

Comment: You are right, I think I'm just being stubborn in trying to see if there is a way with the Field calculator :-)

Comment: Would you know how to select several values at the same time to filter results? For example in the "city column" select all instances with "Rome" and "Paris"?

Comment: I respect that stubbornness ;-)

Comment: Re. the filter for multiple values, its the same syntax as Erik has used in the accepted answer: `"Column 1" IN ('X','Y','Z')`  I have added a picture to the answer to show a "compound filter expression"

Comment: Thank you, just saw the picture appear!

Comment: Is there also a way to do the same thing with the filter form ? By writing that the "diameter" field contains 100 or 150 ? Just trying to understand the different ways of doing it. Thank you!

Comment: If there is a way to do it with the filter form its eluding me :P